# Javascript. Using a class to refer a transition in another

Tags: javascript, html, function, this

I am making an Image slider. It zooms on hover and navigates through pictures in respect of an Input button named .btnNext. The Images are held in an array named .myImages. Everything is working fine so far though one problem has persisted. After .myImages transition takes effect and on hover of the button the transition loses it's effect making the button rather mundane. How can I change the code below to incorporate the fact that the transition called on another element  has taken effect & stays in place. Any help Is appreciated. :}

```
 **Code**

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.myImages').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('transition');
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('transition');
  });
});
```

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Don't worry. If you come across this I have figured it out now. I replicated the above code and changed .myImages with .btnNext and changed "this" to .myImages. Now It works perfect. Image enlarges and button causes no interruption to the transition in effect. I love computers :}